# How to disable media sharing in Windows Media Player 12

Tags: windows-media-player

I have disabled the service for the player but why is it enabled in the first place and how do I get rid of it? (Do not want to play media sharing at work)

Answer (score 9):

From [How To Disable Windows Media Player 12 Sharing](http://www.unplggd.com/unplggd/good-questions/how-to-disable-windows-media-player-12-sharing-good-questions-123914) :

1. Go to **Network and Sharing Center** (found by clicking your wireless/Ethernet icon in your taskbar)
2. Select **Homegroup and Sharing Options**
3. Select **Choose Media Streaming Options**
4. Click **Block All**

Comment: WMP12 doesn't have the "simple-minded solution"

Answer (score 7):

It's also possible to disable the media sharing from Services

1. Click "Start" and select the "Control Panel."
2. Go to "Administrative Tools" and open "Services."
3. Find "Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service" and double-click on it.
4. Click "Stop" under the "General" tab and then select "Ok.", or set the service to "Disabled".

http://www.ehow.com/how_7209048_disable-windows-media-player-sharing.html

Comment: It still works years later. For anyone else with this problem consider changing the `start-up` type to **disabled** it's on the same tab mention in step 4.

Comment: FWIW the setting out of the box is **manual**. Also, you may be interested to reset [this](https://jordanmills.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/resolved-windows-media-player-shared-libraries-wont-show-up-on-other-devices/) and [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/firewall-port-registry-settings) keys (and the firewall rule) to reset everything to the default state.

Answer (score 1):

1.Open Notepad and Paste:

@echo off

sc config "WMPNetworkSvc" start= disabled

sc stop "WMPNetworkSvc"

pause

2.Save File (Example): _WMP_Sharing_Disable.bat

3.Right-Button => Run as Administrator